# Gibbs sampler: Conditional distribution with nested latent variable distributions

Tags: bayesian, sampling, gibbs

I have the following model (simplified here for the description). The obsvered variable is $y_i$ which is a linear function of some random variable $\eta_i$ and a random error term $\epsilon_i$:

$y_{i} = \eta_i + \epsilon_i$

Now, $\eta_i$ is also a linear function of some random variable plus another random error term:

$\eta_{i} = b \cdot \tau_i  + \delta_i$

and finally $\tau_i$ is something like

$\tau_i = c \tau_i + \xi_i$ <-> $\tau_i = c' \cdot \xi_i$

The goal is to estimate the coefficients $b$ and $c$, and the variances of $\epsilon_i$, $\delta_i$, and $\tau_i$ with a Bayesian approach. Say $\theta = (b,c,\sigma^2_{\epsilon},\sigma^2_{\tau}, \sigma^2_{\xi}$). The posterior is proportional to

$f(\theta, \eta_i, \tau_i | y_i ) \propto f(y|\eta_i,\theta)f(\eta_i|\tau_i,\theta)f(\tau_i|\theta)f(\theta)$

I am not an expert in Bayesian estimation, but my understanding is for the Gibbs sampler I would need the conditional distributions $f(\eta_i| \cdot)$ and $f(\tau_i| \cdot)$, that is I need to sample $\eta_i$ and $\tau_i$. I was wondering whether I really need this or whether there is a way - given the construction of the model - to circumvent the sampling of one of the two variables. For instance, I can easily derive the marginal distribution of $f(\eta_i|\theta)$ where $\tau_i$ is integrated out. Any hints - pointers to papers/books - are appreciated (and sorry when this is a silly problem/question).

Thanks
Stefan

Comment: This is called [collapsed Gibbs sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_sampling#Collapsed_Gibbs_sampler). This paper also discusses partially collapsed Gibbs sampling: https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/~dvandyk/Research/08-jasa-pcg.pdf

Comment: @jblood94. Thank you this! I think that this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Since $y_i=bc'\xi_i+\delta_i+\epsilon_i$, it is unclear to me why the hierarchical structure is at all necessary. Note that this representation means only $bc'$ is identifiable.